# Как подгружать системные шрифты?

Tags: javascript, шрифты, flash

Как подгружать шрифты установленные в системе на примере сайта https://wordmark.it

Задача стоит такая: предположим, пользователь заходит на похожий сайт, нажимает на кнопку «Загрузить системные шрифты» и после нажатия (пока без авторизации) ему выпадает список с его системными шрифтами.

[image: Список системных шрифтов]

Как такое можно реализовать? Можно обойтись без Flash, а только с помощью JS? Что изучить, чтобы самостоятельно такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Грузить системные шрифты нет нужды, они же на устройстве пользователя.

В JS нет доступа до всех доступных шрифтов.
Можно разве что перебором проверять - есть ли такой шрифт или нет.
Если есть - создаём пример с нужным `font-family`.

У `flash` есть доступ к этому списку, но эта устаревшая технология, которую даже разработчик уже не поддерживает, не говоря об остальных.

[Такой же вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3368837/6275986).